# How can log-in using $http.post?

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

Ionic Controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function() {
        $http.post('https://mywebsite/login', $scope.email) THIS PART IS TOTALLY WRONG
        .success(function(data) {
            $state.go('improvements');
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'User/Password is Wrong'
            });
        });
    }
})
```

I'm trying to login in a web using an ionic APP, so I used inspect element in form log-in from the website that i want login and I got this:

WEB that I want login

```
<form action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+NAqH2wFj+OC3q5kX3UWLymVHDzpS9ei8a9/F5O8MM76EM6Fhf/RyOVRpCeYmGMtoxzB43Gf70WLbR+1EqD5xA==">

        <label for="session_email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="session[email]" id="session_email">

        <label for="session_password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="session[password]" id="session_password">

        <label class="checkbox inline" for="session_remember_me">
            <input name="session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="session[remember_me]" id="session_remember_me">
            <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
</label>
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Anyone could help me ?  and I'm  so sorry for this newbie question

Comment: These two pieces of code couldn't be more different.  The first one isn't passing any password value, and the second one isn't even angular/ionic.

Comment: I know that, but the second code is the Website that i want login and the first one is my IonicAPP, but could you explain me how can i pass email and password ?

Comment: you don't log in to a *website*, you log in to a *server*.  This HTML page is submitting a form, which has some sort of `authenticity_token` along with other form values.  it's not really clear if your server would even allow a login without this.

Comment: if your question is how to send multiple values in `$http.post`, they need to be sent as an object that the server understands; JSON for example.

Comment: @Claies Yes the server needs a authenticity_token to login, but If I pass a password, email and persist the token it will not work ?

Comment: @Claies could you show me an example ? I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Really not clear what your specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl it is simple, how can i pass multiple values in my $http.post ? I think i need to pass email and password but i dont know how to do that

Comment: you pass an object as second argument

Comment: @charlietfl but how can I create a json object with these two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {
  utf8: "the utf8 value"'
  authenticity_token : "token value",
  session:{
    email:"email@mail.com",
    password : "apassword"
  }
};

$http.post("https://mywebsite/login", params)
.success(function(data) {
    $state.go('improvements');
}).error(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Login failed!',
        template: 'User/Password is Wrong'
    });
});
```